# Virtual function in class template, that doesn't have the template type as parameter/return value

Tags: c++, class, templates, virtual

As far as I know, templated virtual functions aren't allowed/possible due to the undefined size of the vtable.

On the other hand, virtual functions inside a class template which don't use the template type seem to be allowed, right?

What about a virtual function that doesn't use the template type as parameter or return type but works on data of the template type? Would that be valid C++?

I have already done some testing and it seems to work.

My Code looks like this:

(Note: For reasons of readability this is only the basic structure, not the real code).

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
public:
    virtual bool compare(void) {
        // Basic implementation
        return ((value1 + value2) < value3);
    }
protected:
    T value1, value2, value3;
}


/**
 * Derived from Base<ComplexClass> where
 * ComplexClass is a Class providing
 * a int Value through .getInt()
**/
class Derived : Base<ComplexClass> {
    bool compare(void) {
        return ((value1.getInt() + value2.getInt()) < value3.getInt());
    }
}

main {
    Base<int> *intBase = new Base<int>();
    Base<double> *doubleBase = new Base<double>();
    Base<ComplexClass> *complexBase = new Derived();

    intBase->compare(); // Should call base function
    doubleBase->compare(); // Should also call base function
    complexBase->compare(); // Should call the compare function of Derived
}
```

As far as i can tell this works like I excepted. Is this just a lucky coincidence or is this valid/good C++ style?

If it's valid, could someone please explain what's happening inside and why some people say it's forbidden/bad practice to derive from class templates and use virtual functions inside of class templates?

Thank you in advance!

PS: I know something similar could have been done by template specialization but I'd like to know if it's also possible this way.

Comment: It's perfectly valid, and works just as any other (non template) class with virtual functions.

Comment: template method != template class

Comment: I think what Paranaix wants to say is: The problem is with *virtual function templates*, not with *virtual member functions of class templates*. As long as there's a fixed amount of member functions, the size of the vtable is known and there's no problem. But a member function template can be instantiated for any number of template arguments at various places (and for different arguments in each Translation Unit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q** As far as I know, templated virtual functions aren't allowed/possible due to the undefined size of the vtable.

**A** You can have virtual function in class templates.

Example code that compiles and links:

```
 template <typename T>
 struct Base
 {
    virtual T doSomething(T const& in) = 0;
    Base(T const& data) : data_(data) {}
    T data_;
 };

 struct Concrete : public Base<int>
 {
    Concrete(int d) : Base(d) {}

    virtual int doSomething(int const& in)
    {
       return data_*in;
    }
 };

 int main()
 {
    Concrete a(20);
    int b = a.doSomething(10);
 }
```

**Q** On the other hand, virtual functions inside a class template which don't use the template type seem to be allowed, right?

**A** The virtual functions of a class template can use anything -- not restricted to not using the template tye.

My example should make that clear.

**Q** What about a virtual function that doesn't use the template type as parameter or return type but works on data of the template type? Would that be valid C++?

**A** Yes, it will.

Again, my example should make that clear.

**EDIT: Extended example**

```
 template <typename T>
 struct Base
 {
    virtual T fun1(T const& in) = 0;

    virtual T fun2(int in) = 0;

    virtual int fun3(T const& in) = 0;

    virtual int fun4(int in) = 0;

    Base(T const& data) : data_(data) {}
    T data_;
 };

 struct Concrete : public Base<int>
 {
    Concrete(int d) : Base(d) {}

    virtual int fun1(int const& in)
    {
       return data_*in;
    }

    virtual int fun2(int in)
    {
       return fun1(in);
    }

    virtual int fun3(int const& in)
    {
       return fun1(in);
    }

    virtual int fun4(int in)
    {
       return fun1(in);
    }
 };

 int main()
 {
    Concrete a(20);
    int b = a.fun1(10);
    int c = a.fun2(10);
    int d = a.fun3(10);
    int e = a.fun4(10);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was pretty sure that I've red somewhere that class templates with virtual functions using the template type behave like virtual member function templates (which isn't allowed). But obviously I've gotten something wrong. One more thing: your example code won't compile since the virtual functions are pure virtual. For some reason my compiler needs at least empty brackets instead of the '=0'. Is that a problem with my compiler or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @user1271373 I had no issue compiling and linking the simple example and the extended example with g++ 4.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly valid. However, here you can have the same behaviour with specialization or just overloading, e.g.

```
template<typename T>
struct Base
{
    bool compare() const { return val(value1) + val(value2) < val(value3); }

protected:
    T value1, value2, value3;

private:
    template<typename U>
    static U val(U a) { return a; }
    static int val(const ComplexClass& a) { return a.getInt(); }
};
```

Better keep virtual functions for when it's really needed.

And try to gather as much as possible shared code in a single place, minimizing what is to be specialized.